# I got the error unclosed regular expression in my jsfiddle

Tags: reactjs, jsfiddle

I am new to React and jsfiddle.
I try to program something basic in React by the JSfiddle but nothing appear on the screen and I get the errors "unclosed regular expression" and "Unrecoverable syntax error".
I didnt find any solution or explanation, why these errors appear, not in the web and here.
The following is the my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eli12m/or9uxwch/38/
Can you please tell me what i am missing.
The following is the code:

```js
class InputPhoneNumber extends React.component{
 render(){
   return(
    );
  }
}


class ReadOnlyPhoneNumber extends React.component{
 render(){
   return(
    );
  }
}

class PhoneNumberInputDisplay extends React.component{
 render(){
   return (<h1>Hello World</h1>); /* Here the errors */
  }
}

  ReactDOM.render(
    <PhoneNumberInputDisplay />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div id="root" class="container">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad synthaxe, you can't write

```
return();
```

And you can't return nothing. Try to use the message outputed by the console to figure out what is wrong before asking :)
In chrome, right click anywhere => inspect => console tab

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I removed those lines with the wrong syntax. but the error I mentioned in my question still appear and in the same place. In the console I get the following message which I didnt find explanation to it in the web and here: "Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null". Do you know what I am missing?

Comment: React.Component not React.component